# Generating 3D image using stack of 2D images

Tags: python, numpy, graphics, 3d

I'm trying to generate a 3D images using stack of 2D grayscale images in python. I currently have the images, mask, and mask output. I tried creating an ndarray by adding an axis to my images but this didn't seems to work.

This is what I wrote:

```
# load images
images_gray = []

#x, y= images[0].shape
#z= len(frames)
#threeD= np.ndarray([x,y,z]) #3D
threeD=[]

for i in range(len(images)):  

    frame= cv2.imread(path+'/images/' + str(i))

    #convert to grayscale then save
    images_gray.append(rgb2gray(frame))
    
    #create a polygon
    coordinates=coord[i]
    coordinates = [[y,x] for [x,y] in coordinates] #change order for polygon2mask
    polygon = np.array(coordinates)
    #create a mask
    mask= polygon2mask(images_gray[i].shape, polygon)

    #apply mask
    result=ma.masked_array(images_gray[i],  np.invert(mask))
    temp=result[... ,np.newaxis]
    threeD.append(temp)
```

The resulted output shape for threeD is (#of frames, image hight, image width, 1). I don't know where the 1 come from, and I also expected the order to be (x, y, z) = (image hight, image width, #of frames). The output is wrong and I wasn't able to view it using plt as I got type error saying invalid shape.

For the z, I thought about setting a value of 0.1 that would represent the thickness, not sure how to set that up.

I'm also not sure if my approach is correct or not; do I have to create a points clouds instead? mesh? any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps you want np.dstack at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html

Comment: investigate your use of `np.newaxis`